# How to query a Treeview items font on tkinter tkk?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am building an interface that has a `Treeview` to display a list of items.
I would like for some items to be displayed with italic font.

I understood that a `Treeview` can apply a `tag` to its items, tags have bound properties - including a font that will be applied to the items containing that tag.

#### First try

I have tried creating a tag with a new font, passing only the *italic* property to such font, but the results were awful:

```py
treeview.tag_configure(
    'content_modified', font=font.Font(slant='italic'))
```

[image: Treeview sample with new font for tag]

I realized that I was creating a whole new font, not only an *italic* effect font, and the base font not necessarily is the same as the one being used by the `Treeview`.

#### Second try

After reading [the documentation about default fonts](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl8.6/TkCmd/font.html#M31), I noticed that the `Treeview` *probably* (?) uses a font named `TkTextFont` for its items, so I decided to make a copy of it and apply an italic modification to the copy, and then use the new font as a property to the tag:

```py
italic_font = font.Font(font=font.nametofont('TkTextFont'))
italic_font.config(slant='italic', weight='bold')

treeview.tag_configure(
    'content_modified', font=italic_font)
```

[image: Treeview sample with font modified from]

I got the desired result visually, but the code is bothering me.

#### The problem

- I would like to be able to query the `Treeview` for the font that it is using, and I could not find a way to do that. I would rather copy the queried font instead of a *global named font* expecting it to be the one that the `Treeview` is using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comment section. In ttk are some differences due the style engine and some options are not longer *in the widgets themselves*.

> The Tile widgets are mostly compatible with the corresponding Tk
> widgets. They support the same set of widget commands and the same
> essential options. However, most of the appearance-related options
> have been removed — more precisely, they’ve been moved — **out of the
> widgets themselves and into the style system**.

In another section of the same document it is stated that:

> Layouts use the same hierarchical naming scheme as elements, falling
> back to the parent theme if no match is found. Styles also use
> hierarchical names, but with a different fallback chain. The search
> for maps and **defaults** proceeds along the name hierarchy, but
> terminates at the “root” **style named “.”**. The parent theme is not
> consulted. Theme- wide default settings like -background and -font can
> be set on the root style, overriding them if necessary on individual
> widget-specific styles

So if nothing is defined a `ttk.widgets` grabs the parents value, since I'm not aware of any parent except the *root style*, I would consider this as the style that it grabs from. `print(style.configure('.','font'))` prints `TkDefaultFont` and when I configure this font, all items in the Treeview changes **without** any call to `tree.tag_configure`, which leads me to the conclusion I have the right font.

But be aware that this font most likely is used in more style schemas than just the Treeview that you will configure with it too.

[Source Document](http://tktable.sourceforge.net/tile/tile-tcl2004.pdf)

Example Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import font


root = tk.Tk()
widget = ttk.Treeview(root, style='my.Treeview')
widget['columns']=('value1')

widget.heading(column="#0", text='Home')
widget.column('#0', stretch = True, minwidth=80, width = 180)

widget.heading(column="#1", text="value1")
widget.column('#1', stretch = True, minwidth=80, width = 180)
widget.insert("", "end", iid=0, text="Insert Me", values="here",
              tags='my_tag')
widget.insert(0, "end", iid=None, text="Insert Me2")
widget.pack()
style = ttk.Style()
italic_font = tk.font.nametofont(style.configure('.','font'))
italic_font.config(slant='italic',weight='bold')
```